# MongoDB Where Not Exists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to do the following (from SQL) in MongoDB but can't seem to get the hang of it. I think the trick is using unwind, but I'm not sure.

```
select p.id, count(*)
from model.patients p
join model.patientAddresses pa on pa.PatientId = p.Id
where p.lastname like '%a%' and not exists
    (select * 
    from model.patients p2
    join model.PatientAddresses pa2 on pa2.PatientId = p2.Id
    where pa2.relatedpatientid = p.id
    )
group by p.id
having count(*) >1
```

I have:

```
db.Foo.aggregate( [ { $unwind : "$relatedNames" }, 
     { $match: { relatedNames: 'x,' name: 'x'}] )
```

The corresponding structure for a "Foo" in MongoDB is:

```
{
  name: ''
  relatedNames: ['', '', '', '']
}
```

And I want to find Foos where Name = 'x' and there are no other Foos where RelatedNames contains 'x'

Assistance appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure the SQL subselect example is helpful given you can't do joins or subselects in MongoDB. If you're just trying to find Foos where `relatedNames` includes `x` you could use a more straightforward query: `db.Foo.find({"relatedNames": "x"})` (and add an index on `releatedNames` array to make the query more performant). If you are trying to do more specific filtering of the `relatedNames` array I think the question needs a bit more detail.

Comment: Also, you should have the `$match` first in your pipeline to reduce the number of candidate documents to process (and if needed, repeat the `$match` after `$unwind` of the array). See [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) for more tips.